# how to swipe across UINavigationController tree leaves without pushing?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

This app provides 6 screens of detail form input that are accessed through a master table view using a `UINavigationController`.

So the user starts are the master screen used as a menu, and drills down each of the detail view in turn. The depth of the tree is 2: at level 1, there is the master view (the menu). At level 2, there are all the 6 detail views.

Now, the most common workflow is to go through each of the 6 detail screens in turn, in a linear fashion. Having to go back to the menu each time is cumbersome at best.

I would therefore like to offer the user the possibility to go from one detail screen to the next or previous with a swipe gesture.

How can I do that?

I can set up 2 `UIGestureRecognisers`. No problem. I even linked them to a push segue, and it works, but this is not the behaviour I'd like: I want the depth to stay at 2. In other words, I would like the segues to *replace* not *push* the view at the top of the navigation stack.

What would be the best way?

Second: the views switch one the swipe gesture is over. I would rather have the animation start *during* the swipe, with the user having the opportunity to change her mind when watching the next/previous view partially appear, exactly as the photo app handled swiping from one photo to the next/previous.

Is that even possible?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are looking for something like [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) with [UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle).

You can segue to that `UIPageViewController` from your master tableView and add your 6 detail VC to it as pages.

Here is a [tutorial](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=it&u=http://www.devapp.it/wordpress/t111-come-utilizzare-uipageviewcontroller-con-lo-storyboard.html&prev=/search?q=uipageviewcontroller%2bexample&start=20&safe=active&sa=N&hl=en&biw=1597&bih=674&sa=X&ei=7LF3Uej8KcGAtAa8zoGYBg&ved=0CE0Q7gEwBTgU) on how to use a `UIPageViewController` in a storyboard.

Please note that this scroll style is only available on iOS6.0+.